# ClassNotFoundException in ObjectInputStream.readObject()

Tags: java, serialization, classnotfoundexception, objectinputstream

I'm trying to cast an object passed by my client application to an object of identical class in my server application.

The error I'm currently receiving in my server application is:

```
mei 02, 2012 11:44:43 PM server.UserThread process
SEVERE: null
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: client.User
```

The object is being received by the server via Socket -> ObjectInputStream.

So I was wondering if you guys could help me cast the client.User class to my Server.User class. The only thing that works is placing the packages inside 1 project and then defining the exact location of the class.

Code can always be supplied.

Comment: "ClassNotFoundException" suggests that your server doesn't have access to the same class file being used in the client.  Are you doing something funny with classloaders?

Comment: Did you create 2 identical classes or are you using the **same** class? You should be using the later.

Comment: Showing some code might help.

Comment: I'm not using classloaders atm.

Comment: I have created 2 identical classes. Which is why I'm trying to typecast.

Comment: You can't do that. Two identical classes are not the same class, so you can't typecast between them. They have to be the same class name in the same package and loaded by the same class loader.

Comment: So, I'm working with Netbeans here but this basically means I have to make 1 project with multiple packages in which I can use the 1 class between both packages?

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what I just said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cast the client.User class to my Server.User class

You can't. They aren't the same class. They are in different packages. They are different. If you want to share a class between server and client, you have to share a single .class file. That might imply creating a third package for shared stuff.

Comment: Thank you after a bit of trial and error I found the perfect solution.
This helped a lot.

Comment: *You* found? *I* provided.

Answer (score 0):

The classes need to be the same, as some users suggest in reply to your question. It doesnt seem like a good choice to use the default serialization procces to flatten and inflate your objects.
You can define your own protocol if you use the [Externalizable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) interface, instead of Serializable,
you can use writeExternal and readExternal to customize the serialization procces.

If you are trying to send object from server to client, I really discourage the use of the object streams. May I suggest [Protobuff](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) to do this?

> Protobuff:
>
> Protocol Buffers are a way of encoding structured data in an efficient yet extensible format. Google uses Protocol Buffers for almost all of its internal RPC protocols and file formats.